# What do you do change in the such a data model Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-cli

I have task to create a social feed(news feed). I think no need to explain the standard functionality - all are how as FB.
I chose solution *apache cassandra* and designed a data column **Posts** for storing information about posts users:

```
CREATE TABLE Posts (
  post_id  uuid,
  post_at  timestamp,
  user_id  text,
  name     varchar,
  category set<text>,
  link     varchar,
  image    set<varchar>,
  video    set<varchar>,
  content  map<text, text>,
  private  boolean,

  PRIMARY KEY ((post_id, user_id), post_at)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (post_at DESC) COMPACT STORAGE;
```

The next table contains id user posts:

```
CREATE TABLE posts_user (
  post_id  bigint,
  post_at  timestamp,
  user_id  bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY ((post_id), post_at, user_id)
)

WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (post_at DESC) AND COMPACT STORAGE;
```

How do you think, is it good? What do you do change in the such a data model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of questions and a couple of improvements that jump out.

1. COMPACT STORAGE is deprecated now (if you want to take advantage of CQL 3 features).  I do not think that you can create your table `Posts` as you have defined above since it uses CQL 3 features (collections) with COMPACT STORAGE as well as declaring more than one column that is not part of the primary key.
2. `posts_user` has completely different key types than `Posts` does.  I am not clear on what the relationship between the two tables is, but I imagine that `post_id` is supposed to be consistent between them, whereas you have it as a `uuid` in one table and a `bigint` in the other.  There are also discrepancies with the other fields.
3. Assuming `post_id` is unique and represents the id of an individual post, it is strange to have it as the first part of a compound primary key in the `Posts` table since if you know the `post_id` then you can already uniquely access the record. Furthermore, as it is part of the partition key it also prevents you from doing wider selects of multiple posts and taking advantage of your `post_at` ordering.

The common method to fix this is to create a dedicated index table to sort the data the way you want.

E.g.

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
  id       uuid,
  created  timestamp,
  user_id  uuid,
  name     text,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE posts_by_user_index (
  user_id    uuid,
  post_id    uuid,
  post_at    timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id,post_at,post_id)
  WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (post_at DESC)
);
```

Or more comprehensively:

```
CREATE TABLE posts_by_user_sort_index (
  user_id    uuid,
  post_id    uuid,
  sort_field text,
  sort_value text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((user_id,sort_field),sort_value,post_id)
);
```

However, in your case if you only wish to select the data one way, then you can get away with using your `posts` table to do the sorting:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
  id       uuid,
  post_at  timestamp,
  user_id  uuid,
  name     text,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id,post_at,id)
  WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (post_at DESC)
);
```

It will just make it more complicated if you wish to add additional indexes later since you will need to index each post not just by its post id, but by its user and post_at fields as well.

Comment: Thank you for response. I have left a couple of questions: Why only one key **id** at table **post**? I need request last notes (using LIMIT) from table **posts** ordered by **created** column to some given _user_id_ users. If I understood you correctly, at first I need request all **id** from table **posts_by_user_index** ordering by **post_at** and limit [x] to some **user_id** which I have to (1,2,3,4 .etc). After the second query to table **posts** with selected **posts.id** from a last query. Do I correctly talk?

Comment: When i create table **posts_by_user_sort_index** i get error: Bad Request: line 5:7 no viable alternative at input 'value'

Comment: Please, edit you answer above. I found a cause of query error: The field **sort value** must have underscore sort**_**value.

Comment: @Alice Good catch on the missing `_`, my apologies.  Depending on how many different ways you want to sort your data, you either need a separate index as shown first, or if you just want to sort by created time only then you can use the definition for `posts` that I put at the end.

Comment: Thank you, can you see please this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530984/the-correct-param-to-set-function-cassandra

Comment: Also want to ask author of answer, what will be row key for table **Posts**?

Comment: @Alice It depends on which schema you are using for `posts`.  If using the first suggested schema, then the partition key is simply `id`, and if using the second schema then the partition key is `user_id`.  The primary key for the second schema, however, is `user_id, post_at, id` which allows you to sort/search `posts` directly by the created (post_at) time.

Comment: So if i want insert data via php i must do:                   `$cassandra->set(
    'user_id',
    array(
        'post_at' => time(),
        'user_id' => 1',
        'name'    => 'Alice 
    )
);`

Comment: @Alice Sorry, I am not familiar with accessing Cassandra via PHP at all, so I am not sure exactly what parameters you need to pass in order to perform an update.

Comment: Can you please tell for what fields: **sort_field**, **sort_value**